# Consolidating 2 separate DHCP servers into 1 DHCP cluster

Tags: windows, dhcp

I am looking to be pointed in the right direction for migrating my two current DHCP servers (which are each located on a DC...) to 1 DHCP cluster separate from our DCs. This is all coming from and going to be on Windows.

Here is what is going on.

1 DHCP server for one location handing out DHCP for hypothetical subnet 10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0

1 DHCP server for one location handing out DHCP for hypothetical subnet 10.2.0.0/255.255.0.0

I am looking to setup 2 (or 3) new DHCP servers and cluster them for fail-over, and have it setup to do DHCP for both 10.1 and 10.2 networks.

What is the best way for me to go about starting this process?

Can I use the DHCP export/import commands to merge 2 DHCP servers into one, or am I going to have to use the commands for one server and then manually setup the other?

Would it be more appropriate to setup the 2-3 server cluster before beginning the migration or after?

Comment: Which Windows version is used? Usually you create the failover cluster and then assign the DHCP server role inside the cluster. You should even be able to import your settings.

Comment: I will be coming from Windows 2012R2 and going to 2016.

Comment: You have two options: 1) [create a "real" failover cluster and add the DHCP role](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/failover-clustering-overview) 2) [use DHCP failover](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831385(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: Will there be any issue with the following. DHCP1 on 10.1.0.1, DHCP2, on 10.1.0.2, DHCP 3 on 10.2.0.1, and DHCPCluster on 10.1.0.3?

Comment: Just export, merge, then add the scope manually, import reservations and things you need from the dump. After that, build a failover-cluster.